# Primeng MenuItem with command not working

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I have create a table component and I am adding a split button for each row and trying to call the function but not working

Here is the function I am using to create the menu items

```
getItems(rowData: any): MenuItem[] {
  const items: MenuItem[] = [
  {
      label: 'Edit', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-check', command: () => this.update(rowData)
  },
  { label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-times' }];
    return items;
  }

  update(employee: any): void {
    this.isEditMode = true;
    this.addEmployee = true;
    this.employee = { ...employee };
}
```

Here is how I am calling this inside my component

```
<app-prime-table [data]="data" [columns]="columns" [customBodyTemplate]="customBodyTemplate"
                [globalFilters]="columns" [displayFilter]="true">
            </app-prime-table>
            <ng-template #customBodyTemplate let-rowData>

                <tr>
                    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                        <div *ngIf="col.type == 'button' && rowData.isActive">
                            <!-- <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-pencil" (click)="update(rowData)"
                                class="p-button-rounded p-button-primary mr-1"></button>
                            <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-trash" (click)="delete(rowData)"
                                class="p-button-rounded p-button-danger"></button> -->
                        <p-splitButton label="Actions" [model]="getItems(rowData)" appendTo="body">
                        </p-splitButton>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="!col.type">{{rowData[col.field]}}</div>
                        <div *ngIf="col.type == 'date'">{{formatDate(rowData[col.field])}}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
```

I can see the items but couldn't perform any action on it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming due to using a function to get the list of values for the dropdown, due to the use of a function, a new reference to `items` is always getting created due to change detection running. To solve this issue, simply initialize the dropdown items once, you will notice that we have an `event` property on the command function, which we can use to access the data and perform actions!

We can use `styleClass` to introduce a class to style the menu

We can use `onDropdownClick` to store the active row and use that to perform the menu actions!

code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../../domain/product';
import { ProductService } from '../../service/productservice';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-demo.html',
})
export class TableBasicDemo implements OnInit {
  products!: Product[];
  items: MenuItem[];
  activeRow!: Product | null;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.getItems();
    this.productService.getProductsMini().then((data) => {
      this.products = data;
    });
  }

  getItems(): MenuItem[] {
    const items: MenuItem[] = [
      {
        label: 'Edit',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-check',
        command: (event: any) => {
          console.log(event);
          this.update(this.activeRow);
        },
        styleClass: 'red',
      },
      { label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-times', styleClass: 'blue' },
    ];
    return items;
  }

  update(employee: any): void {
    alert(JSON.stringify(employee));
  }
}
```

html

```
 <div class="card">
  <p-table [value]="products" [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '50rem' }">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p-splitButton
            (onDropdownClick)="activeRow = product"
            label="Actions"
            [model]="items"
            appendTo="body"
            data-id="product.code"
          >
          </p-splitButton>
        </td>
        <td>{{ product.code }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.category }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/knwhhm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftable-basic-demo.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftable-basic-demo.html)

Comment: Naren Murali thanks but I need to pass the row data on clicking the edit is it possible?

Comment: @Developer `data.item` is the row data you want! try `console.log(data)` to check the event object!

Comment: Yes like I would like to show name as Bamboo and code as f230fh0g3

Comment: Also is it possible to apply colour to the items like for edit blue and delete red

Comment: Naren Murali Thank you so much it works as expected style is not getting applied I will take a look

Comment: Hi Naren is it possible to add menu conditional based on row like I will have a role in my data I would like to show an extra option when he is not admin?

Comment: @Developer use a ternary condition `dataItem.isAdmin ? adminItems : normalItems`

Comment: Thanks I handled it in a different way, showing item as default and hiding it on clicking the drop down `rowClick(rowData: any) {
        console.log(rowData);
        if (rowData.role !== "Employee")
            this.items[0].label = "Demote";
        this.activeRow = rowData;
    }`